# How to edit value of date input in HTML via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have my date in this string

```
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    var period = document.getElementById("date_Select").value;
    var month = document.getElementById("month_Select").value;
    var day = document.getElementById("day_Select").value;
    var date1 = year + "-" +month+"-"+day;

    document.getElementById("date_input1").value = new Date(date1);
```

The default value of the date changes back to null. I've also tried using a direct string value:

```
document.getElementById("date_input1").value = date1;
```

It has the same effect, being null.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/xitekudage/1/edit

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/t80wt6y1/

Comment: If your date_select, month_select and day_select fields aren't static and require user input then date1 is being set to null when the document loads.
Try setting Date1 in the onChange event.

Comment: *"The default value of the date changes back to null."* That means what? What defaults to null? Make a sample code that shows the exact problem with a snipplet.

Comment: @epascarello The date input has a default value set to the first day of the month.

Comment: Still does not answer the question.... You mean the actual `defaultValue`? You need to show the code running that has the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are assigning a date object to date_input1 which is invalid. you can assign only string values to date_input1 element try using method toDateString().

try using this code:

`var date=new Date();
date.setDate(document.getElementById("date_Select").value);
date.setMonth(document.getElementById("month_Select").value-1)
document.getElementById("date_input1").value =date.toDateString();`
please don't create unnecessary Object your work can be done using only one object.